# How do I create a shortcut for windows 10 to rename comments attribute or any attribute?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, user-experience

I am have searched all over the internet to find a solution to my problem.
My problem is  I want to add comments to several different video files on windows 10. Opening Properties and Switching to detail tab and editing the comments is too slow for me.
 How do I make this fast? 
I have thought of creating a windows keyboard shortcut but unable to find information about it. H

Answer (score 0):

You can use an utility like e.g. FFMpeg to add specific tags to videos. I'd also look into Medianfo utility, it has Python wrapper - PyMedianfo.
Then you can use Autohotkey to create an input box and a shortcut that runs the utility to read or write video tags.